# debian package creation without a configure script

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, deb, make, dh-make

I've been trying to package an in house code project but have been having trouble. I can create a package, but the actual binaries are not installed when I run

```
sudo dpkg -i proj_1.0.0+svn02042014-1_amd64.deb
```

I expect this is because there is no 'configure' script in the project, and no reference to $DESTDIR. Instead, when running make install, it just calls a perl script that deploys the files to a dir specified on the terminal.

To create the debian package i have been doing the following:

```
tar -pczf proj-1.0.0+svn02042014.tar.gz proj-1.0.0+svn02042014/
dh_make -e blah@blah.com -f ../proj-1.0.0+svn02042014.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

When running `dpkg --contents proj_1.0.0+svn02042014-1_amd64.deb` i can clearly see that the binaries are not in the package. The only things that are in there are some doc files (i.e. `doc\README`)

I'm guessing that using `dpkg-buildpackage` without a `configure` script is not possible? Is this the case?

Thanks for attention

**Edit:**
proj-1.0.0+svn02042014.tar.gz looks something like:

```
proj-1.0.0+svn02042014/  
--Makefile  
--src/  
----install.pl  
----Makefile  
----blah.cpp
```

Comment: the main point being that, the make files were created by hand, not using autoconf...

Comment: If there's not $DESTDIR support in your Makefile where are binaries created? same dir as blah.cpp?

Comment: the binaries are created in the root of the project (proj)

Comment: due to the non GNU std compliant nature of the source code project i was unable to build a debian source package. So instead i created a debian binary package following the steps given [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/)

Comment: ok, could you please at least vote (or even accept ;-) the answer I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `debian/rules` to include an override of `dh_auto_build` and `dh_auto_install`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh "$@"

override_dh_auto_build:
    cd $(CURDIR) && make

override_dh_auto_install:
    cd $(CURDIR) && make install
    cd $(CURDIR) && cp ./proj_bin debian/proj/usr/bin
    dh_install
```

It may requires some modifications but the basic idea is to call your Makefile from the `debian/rules` and install the binary in `/usr/bin`.

**Note**:

- spaces before the `cd` and `dh` commands are tabs, don't replace them.
- replace `proj_bin` by your binary name (I assumed only one)

Comment: i appreciate this answer may provide a solution to the problem stated +1 , but was not successful in implementing it and so i cannot verify its validity as the correct answer. If another reputable member is able to endorse it, i will consider accepting it.